# What should happen when control reaches __builtin_unreachable?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unreachable-code

I wrote this code:

```
enum Color
{
    kRed,
    kGreen,
    kBlue,
    kUnexistingColor
};

const char* foo(Color color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
        case kRed:
            return "red";
        case kGreen:
            return "green";
        case kBlue:
            return "blue";
        case kUnexistingColor:
        default:
            __builtin_unreachable();

    }
    return "";
}
```

If I call `foo` with an invalid value, my program just terminates silently or returns `"blue"` in some other cases. What should really happen if control reaches the point where `__builtin_unreachable();` is? Should some error message box on Windows appear, or what?

Comment: Remove the enum value kUnexpectedColor and `case kUnexpectedColor:` and just return `nullptr` in default case.

Comment: A side note: Since C++23 we have [std::unreachable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable) for a more standard way to achieve similar result.

Comment: If you want an error message, put an error message there, plus `std::abort` (not `std::exit`, as presumably your program state is corrupted).

Answer (score 6):

You told the compiler that the code is unreachable. If you break that promise, you can expect undefined behavior. This is documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005funreachable):

> If control flow reaches the point of the `__builtin_unreachable`, the program is undefined.

If you want to have well-defined behavior, use something else. It's common to put debug-only assertions in such places so you can detect them when running debug builds.

Another common approach is to throw an exception. When you see a crash dump for an unhandled exception raised at that point, you can deduce the supposed "unreachable" code was reached.

You can also write out a message to your log file. Or you can silently return an "error" value and handle that cleanly by not taking any action.

All this entirely depends on how important it is that you know about it and how critical it is to the continued functioning of your program.

Comment: On some platforms, a volatile access would prevent the execution of any following code.  I don't think the documentation is clear on whether the compiler would treat everything up to and including the volatile access as having defined behaivor, or whether it would assume that reaching a volatile access would imply reaching whatever immediately follows it, and that if nothing after the volatile access would be reachable, the access itself wouldn't be either.

Answer (score 4):

The undefined behavior is useful to make optimizations as the compiler assumes that the situation that leads to undefined behavior will not happen. The particular placement of `__builtin_unreachable()` is likely to be helpful for this.

---

A possible outcome for an optimizing compiler is to replace the `switch` with array lookup, based on `color` as index. This would be very good optimization, considering it produces branchless code.

Now, without `__builtin_unreachable()` the compiler will still have to check the index bounds, and produce conditional jumps. With `__builtin_unreachable()` this can be skipped. Then if you pass unexpected value, the function would give garbage string that may ruin you program, most likely because it will be too long, or it also may potentially have inaccessible memory before the `\0`-terminator, or  it can reach inaccessible memory immediately.

If your program has some security implications, then returning a valid string from some unpredicted memory area can be worse than a crash, because it may expose some data not meant to be exposed, or a string not meant to be a part of some script or query becomes that.

---

Consider using `std::unreachable()` as a portable equivalent, if you can afford switching to C++23.

---

If you don't want the UB on unexpected code branch, instead of exceptions, consider using `abort()`. This will keep some code part exception-free, which may aid optimizations, also if you don't really except some situation, then probably attempting to handle it, even with some written exception handling, may go further wrong.

Returning `nullptr`, as suggested in one of the comments, can only be a good idea if you check the returned value for `nullptr` before any indirections. Otherwise, if you don't check for that, you still have the UB, as with `__builtin_unreachable()`, with optimizations less likely to engage, but still possible, so you don't obtain neither robust optimization, nor safe behavior for unexpected parameter value.